# When are the confessional interviews on MasterChef held during production?

Tags: masterchef

The emotion, verb tense, and wardrobe of the interviewees suggest that the "confession room" interviews are held simultaneously to the events in the competition. This would seem disruptive to the competition itself as well as the production. When are these scenes shot?

Comment: This is a really good question. I have always wondered about this.

Comment: I've been watching Masterchef US lately, and I have the exact same question. When are those interviews shot? If they are shot after the specific episode, then why do those contestants say things like- **I'm really scared for the upcoming pressure test** or **I might go home today** when they already know what has happened. Any thoughts, anyone?

Answer (score 1):

I think they are shot in a separate room after the episodes are over to describe their emotions at a particular point of time. However, there is some ambiguity over this as if a person knows they are eliminated, why would they say they *are* scared to go?

Comment: It's worth remembering that these reality shows are to a large extent scripted, and in the case of competitions like Master Chef, I have no doubt that the producers dictate what is said before the cameras in the post hours.

Comment: Is this a guess, or do you know anything about the filming?